# FPDF adding a page where it's not suppose to -PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have this code that I have made using tutorials of FPDF

```
    <?php
require('fpdf\fpdf.php');


class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header()
    {
        //cabecera de la pagina
        //lgo
        $this->Image('simpca.png',10,10,25);
        //fuente
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        //Movemos a la derecha
        $this->Cell(80);
        //Titulo
        $this->Cell(30,10,utf8_decode('Comprobante de impuesto sobre la renta'));
        //Salto de linea
        $this->Ln(20);

        //fuente
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Carrera el saman, zona idustrial matanzas, puerto ordaz'),0,'L');
        $this->Ln(04);
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Telefonos: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),0,'L');
        $this->Ln(04);
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Correo: XXXXXXXXXX'),0,'L');
        $this->Ln(04);
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Usuario: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),0,'L');
        $fecha=date("d-m-Y");
        $this->Ln(04);
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Fecha: ').$fecha,0,'L');
        $this->Ln(06);
        $this->Ln(06);
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('RETENCIONES DE ISLR'),0,0,'C');
    }



    function Basictable($pdf,$result)
    {
        $i=0;           
        //Datos
        //Set maximum rows per page
        $max = 25;  
        //Set Row Height
        $row_height = 6;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
            if ($i = 25 || $i = 0)
            {
                //adds a page
                $pdf->AddPage();

                //set initial y axis position per page
                $y_axis_initial = 70;
                $y_axis = 69.9;
                //print column titles for the current page
                $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
                $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
                $pdf->SetX(30);
                $pdf->Cell(25,6,'Documento',1,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Numero',1,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Codigo',1,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Fecha',1,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Monto',1,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Objeto',1,0,'L',1);
                $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Retenido',1,0,'L',1);

                //Go to next row
                $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
                //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
                $i = 0;
            }

            $emp_ccodigo  =  $row['emp_ccodigo'];
            $pla_ccodigo  =  $row['pla_ccodigo'];
            $prv_ccodigo  =  $row['prv_ccodigo'];
            $doc_ccodigo  =  $row['doc_ccodigo'];
            $mov_cnumero  =  $row['mov_cnumero'];
            $ret_ccodigo  =  $row['ret_ccodigo'];
            $isr_ffecha   =  $row['isr_ffecha'];
            $time = strtotime($isr_ffecha);
            $isr_ffecha1 = date('d-m-Y',$time);
            $isr_nmonto   =  $row['isr_nmonto'];
            $isr_nobjeto  =  $row['isr_nobjeto'];
            $isr_nreteni  =  $row['isr_nreteni'];

            $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
            $pdf->SetX(30);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
            $pdf->Cell(25,6,$doc_ccodigo,1,0,'L',1);
            $pdf->Cell(30,6,$mov_cnumero,1,0,'L',1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,6,$ret_ccodigo,1,0,'R',1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,6,$isr_ffecha1,1,0,'R',1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,6,$isr_nmonto,1,0,'R',1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,6,$isr_nobjeto,1,0,'R',1);
            $pdf->Cell(20,6,$isr_nreteni,1,0,'R',1);

            //Go to next row
            $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }

    }


    function Footer()
    {
        //pos a 1,5cm del final
        $this->SetY(-15);
        //Arial Italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        //numero depagina
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Pagina ').$this->PageNo().' ',0,0,'C');
    }

}   


/////////////CONECTANDOSE A LA BD////////////////////////
        $servername = "X";
        $username = "X";
        $password = "X";

        // Creando la conexion
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

        // Chequeando la conexion
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        //echo "Connected successfully \n";

        //seleccionando la base de datos
        mysqli_select_db($conn,"X")
          or die("Could not select X");

    $query="select * from islr where prv_ccodigo=106204";       
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error()."<BR>Query: '$query'");


//Create new pdf file
$pdf=new PDF();
//titulos de las columnas
$pdf->Basictable($pdf,$result);
//Send file
$pdf->Output();

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

its adding everything ok, but it looks like something in the while is making the FPDF add a new page, so in the $result i have more than 1 item, and it adds one full page (with header and footer) for every single item i have.

Comment: same with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because your condition is an assignment.

```
 if ($i = 25 || $i = 0)
```

Should be

```
if ($i == 25 || $i == 0)
```